# Searching for html element by Xpath

Tags: c#, html, selenium, xpath

I am trying to search for a html element by using selenium xpath and c#.

This is what I have tried:

```
var element = Driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//img[text()='logo-home.png']/@href"));
  if (element.Displayed)
        {
            Result.Pass();
        }
```

Any suggestions?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: 1) `<img>` elements do not support `href` attributes. 2) Even if they did, the image URL is stored in their `src` attribute, not in their inner text.

Comment: Is there any particular way how I can search for <img> partial link text ?

Comment: *Partial link text* is unclear, especially in an image context. Can you elaborate on what exactly you're trying to match (by editing your question itself)? A markup example would be welcome.

Comment: pls do post the html source code of the element which u r trying to locate

Comment: Can you post the html code of the element/link to the webpage

Comment: @Madhan Thank you guys for reply, the link is 'code' <img src="/images/logo-home.png">   Therefore I would like to find this element by a little part of the link lets say only (home.png).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the below xpath here we are locating the image by its src attribute

```
//img[contains(@src,'home.png')]
```

Hope this helps you..Kindly get back if you face any problems